# how to give the String input with Special characters in Xpath using R selenium

Tags: r, xpath, rselenium

```
result <- z$findElement(using = 'xpath',"//*[contains(text(),'the deal” of hosting major sporting')]")
```

In above command the reference String have special character **the deal”** so ,R gave the Error as

> Error:      Summary: NoSuchElement
>        Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
>        class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
>   but the reference element found in the particular URL.

Comment: Have you tried the unicode character [\u0094](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0094/index.htm) (Cancel Character)? Not sure if this is the one. You might want to browse through [these](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html) in case it isn't. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with your syntax of 'contains' and the use of double quotes.
Check here below the correct syntax:

```
[text()[contains(.,'the deal of hosting major sporting')]]
```

also the error you are getting means that the element wasn't present at the time of checking. This can occur for a number of reasons.Two of the most common are:  1) you checked too early (i.e. a wait should be introduced instead of a delay).

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<locator>))`;

2) Your xpath is wrong (most likely). Noticed you are using //* which means any node so as far as we know, you could be pointing to multiple elements. If you want a more specific xpath answer please post a screenshot with the html code of element you are trying to locate. But I'll take an educated guess on the below:

(your way improved without the ")

```
findElement(using = 'xpath',"//*[contains(text(),'the deal of hosting major sporting')]");
```

and if that does not work, go for this:

```
findElement(using = 'xpath',"//*[text()[contains(.,'the deal of hosting major sporting')]]");
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for reply,the web page contain the content with ** "**